# How to mount with 'strictatime'

Tags: filesystems, mount, nfs

I have tried this:

```
# mount -o strictatime someip:/fs/share /mnt/mymount
```

After that, when I run `mount` or `cat /proc/mounts`, it doesn't show the `strictatime` for the mount point. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same problem here.  I worked around by first mounting without the strictatime flag.  Whether that flag is there or not, after mounting, the mount point shows having been set to "relatime" (the default) on my system.  I then do a remount with "mount /mnt/mymount -o remount,strictatime".   Now check again with mount.  The mount point shows no "atime" flag at all.  It does not say "strictatime" but it does not say "relatime" either.   But this is how it should be as I have verified that atimes given by the stat utility are now updated upon each read.